# How do I change order of objects based on window size? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: css, html, formatting, bootstrap-4

I am creating a site utilizing the Bootstrap framework, and have a section for an "About Us" for our team with a picture in one `column` and the name/bio in the second `column`. I am handling window change with `@media (max-width: 1199px) {` in the accompanying CSS file.

The way the section is formatted currently is:

```
<div class="container team">
   <h2>Meet the Team</h2>
   <hr>
   <div class="row row-eq-height" id="ethan">
      <div class="col-md-6" id="picture">
         <img src="[Image Link]" width="500" height="350" alt="Ethan Blagg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6" id="bio">
         <div class="row" id="name">
            <h3>Ethan Blagg</h3>
            <hr>
         </div>

         <div class="row" id="info">
            <p> [bio goes here] </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This alternates:

`Picture` | `Name+Bio`

`Name+Bio` | `Picture`

`Picture` | `Name+Bio`

`Name+Bio` | `Picture`

My issue is when I get below `992px` in window width, the formatting changes to:

`Picture`

`Name+Bio`

`Name+Bio`

`Picture`

etc.

How do I change the order of the objects when the size of the window changes?

I have them alternating from left/right in their containers when full size, but when it decreases below a certain size, the formatting goes vertical, as expected, but the order is poorly formatted. Is this something I would have to change in the HTML or CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bootstrap 4's `flexbox` columns, if you want a `@media (max-width: 1199px)` rule to re-order those children, assign a class to the parent row with children you want to re-order, then use the flex `order` property to re-order. To make it `picture + name+bio` consistently, add a class to the rows where `name+bio` comes first, and use `#picture { order: -1; }` in that row to put the picture first.

```css
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .reorder #picture {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container team">
  <h2>Meet the Team</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="row row-eq-height" id="ethan">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="picture">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg" width="500" height="350" alt="Ethan Blagg">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" id="bio">
      <div class="row" id="name">
        <h3>Ethan Blagg</h3>
        <hr>
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="info">
        <p> [bio goes here] </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row row-eq-height reorder" id="ethan">

    <div class="col-md-6" id="bio">
      <div class="row" id="name">
        <h3>Ethan Blagg</h3>
        <hr>
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="info">
        <p> [bio goes here] </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6" id="picture">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg" width="500" height="350" alt="Ethan Blagg">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So right now I'm using `row-eq-height` to keep my picture container the same size as the `column` containing the `name`/`bio` using `display:` `-webkit-box`, `-webkit-flex`,`-ms-flexbox`, and `flex`. When I use your solution, it works only if I comment out this rule (in my CSS). Is there a way to preserve the centering without sacrificing the reordering functionality?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Bootstrap column ordering](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#push-and-pull). It describes how you can use push and pull classes to achieve the result you want.

Comment: This is bootstrap 3, OP's post is tagged with bootstrap 4 and 4 doesn't use floats.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelCoker for noticing that, updated the answer to link to documentation for the correct version.

Comment: You're welcome, but this should be a comment, not a solution. If you're going to answer with a solution, actually provide a solution. Try not to answer with link-only answers.

Comment: So I was able to implement the fix, but I was initially using `row-eq-height` to keep my pictures vertically centered on the text. In order to get the `push/pull` attribute to work as I am wanting it to, I am stuck using `row` instead, which leaves my pictures at the top of the nested container instead of maintaining size. Are you familiar with this?